# Convert string to list. Python [string.split() acting weird]

Tags: python, string, list, split

```
temp = "['a','b','c']"
print type(temp)
#string

output = ['a','b','c']
print type(output)
#list
```

so i have this temporary string which is basically a list in string format . . . i'm trying to turn it back into a list but i'm not sure a simple way to do it . i know one way but i'd rather not use regex

if i use temp.split() I get

```
temp_2 = ["['a','b','c']"]
```

Comment: Why do you have to do this?

Comment: How did you get this string? That will usually tell you how to evaluate it—do the opposite of whatever you did to get the string. To reverse `json.dumps`, use `json.loads`, and so on. If you got it by `repr`, not everything _can_ be reversed, and not everything that can be should be… but `ast.literal_eval` is the answer for things that can/should.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may
>   only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> temp = "['a','b','c']"
>>> l = literal_eval(temp)
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`:

```
>>> temp = "['a', 'b', 'c']"
>>> temp_list = eval(temp)
>>> temp_list
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> temp_list[1]
b
```

Comment: Please don't use `eval`! It is unsafe, as it allowes arbitrary code to be executed.

Comment: You _can_, but you shouldn't. As the [`eval` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) explicitly say.

Comment: More bluntly: `temp = "['a', __import__('os').system('rm -rf /'), 'c']"`.

Comment: I also learn things on this site answering questions. Thanks for the example of why this is dangerous :)